# "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration" settings forgotten after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, reboot

I'm currently running on an Ubuntu 15.04 machine, and I've been attempting to set my Left Caps Lock Key as my Control Key.

After following numerous ways of doing this, I've attempted the above command after changing my keyboard settings as so:

> `sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard`
>
> And edit `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"`

This works brilliantly for my current session, but the system seems to forget my settings every time I reboot the system.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Perhaps this reference may be useful to you: http://dev-loki.blogspot.com/2006/04/mapping-unsupported-keys-with-xmodmap.html